# Select tableViewCell on button click

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView, with custom cells.
In each cell i have a UIButton. When i click the button inside the cell i want that cell to highlight, but when i click o the cell i don't want this to happen. 
Do you know any way to do this?
thank you

until now i have this code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonMethod: (id)sender {
UIButton *b = (UIButton *) sender;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
}
```

but the cell is highlighted also in -didSelectRow.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
NSAssert(cell, @"cell -> nil");
NSDictionary *cellData = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

[cell populateCellWithData:cellData];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Upload ur CellForRowAtIndexPath method too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return nil;
}
```

This way, cells can't be selected when the user taps on them, but you can still select them programatically.

Also using

> selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:

on your `UITableView` , instead of `setSelected:animated:` on `UITableViewCell` might be better. Cells can be reused and the selection will probably disappear when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of tableView.

So you can set this style  in - (IBAction)buttonMethod: (id)sender. You can add this line at the end. See below:

```
- (IBAction)buttonMethod: (id)sender {
       UIButton *b = (UIButton *) sender;
       UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
      [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

}

Comment: it will not work, because cellForRow is called only once, i don't call cellForRow on every Button click, so if I once clicked on the button, and the selectionStyle is changed, then every time when i click the cell, it will select

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add following line in tableView delegate method cellForRowATIndexPath.**

cell.selectionStyle =- UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Comment: check the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Just use UITableViewDelegate like this

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return NO;
}
```

but If I were you, I would change the background color of cell in [buttonMethod:] with  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone